# How to access a key on an array that i recovered on AD with shellscript

Tags: arrays, shell, active-directory, key

First the question, after ill contribute on some idea im working:

Im receiving from AD some information and got an array on one of them.
I want to extract this info so i can use for next part of my project

the script:

`Get-ADUser foo -Properties * | select name, department, manager`

this returns me a table, ill simplify reading:

```
name -> foo
department -> bar
manager -> CN=foo, OU=bar, OU=fubar, OU=foobar
```

**disclaimer: im from BR, so it may look different for you when u receive data(if you trying to reproduce)

**I want to extract The info "foo" from uptable, but i accept even "CN=foo".**

::finalle

My idea is to create automation by taking AD's data and by shell putting into MSWord
There i have some fields that has autocompletion and after this ill need to somehow pass it through shell
The complete goal is

> run a script that the users gives who he wants (by ID), find it and
>   receive the word oppening with all writen, instead of have to stay
>   changing the same document everytime someone needs this

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I manage do get 2 commands that do the job after some time.

```
(get-aduser (get-aduser foobar -Properties manager).manager).name

Get-ADUser -Identity foobar -Properties manager |
Select-Object -Property @{label='Supervisor';expression={$_.manager -replace ',.*$'}}
```

Thanks for the help anyway